# Data type mismatch in criteria expression Excel 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, excel-2007, ado

I am using following query trying to pull data from Access DB to my spreadsheet:

ID`, MgmtVar.LoB,  MgmtVar.`1yr VaR
`FROM`Test DB11_v2.accdb`.MgmtVar MgmtVar
WHERE COB = ?
AND`Entity ID` = ?

I am getting Data Type Mismatch error for COB field which is Date data type (both in DB and in Excel)

Can anyone advise how to use parametrized query in Excel with Date data type as a parameter ?

Many Thanks

Comment: what are you passing in for COB?

Comment: thats referencing cell containing the actual date. It's formatted as a Date

Comment: Side note: shocked you are using MS Access to compute VaR figures :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13687634/3248346) post, it solves a similar problem. Try changing the type from Date to String.

Comment: thanks, although I'd rather not change the type to String, as that would make my life more difficult. I was hoping for some more elegant solution?

Comment: but the issue is that the database does not understand excel's date type, therefore, you have to use string.

Comment: ok I've changed the input cell format to Text and it works.. Even tho the DB field is of Date format. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: sorry, I meant tick that it is the right answer, no big deal.